# Sublists of a list sorted by two different keys

Tags: algorithm, sorting, iteration, sublist

I have an algorithm encoutering the following situation; I would like to know if some improvement seems possible (I don't think it is possible, but I may be wrong).

I have a list `L` of objets. I have two different (and independant) keys for sorting them: `mykey1` and `mykey2`. I can actually sort in both ways the list at the beginning of the algorithm with no significant cost; thus, I have two lists:

```
A = sorted(L, key=mykey1)
B = sorted(L, key=mykey2)
```

(Python syntax, but I think anybody can understand). I could perfectly do anything more (intialize new variables) at this stage as long as the complexity remains below O(*n log n*).

I need to extract *many* sublists of `A`; instead of actually copy the sublists, I would like to use indices (start and end) during the main loop of my algorithm for obvious reasons.

Now, for any arbitrary sublist of `A` (known by the two indices), is there some tricky way to iterate over its objects according the corresponding order (of the very same objects) in `B`?

Here is a quick and dirty example:

```
L = [(7,2), (4,3), (5,9), (1,8)]
mykey1 = lambda e: e[0]
mykey2 = lambda e: e[1]
A = sorted(L, key=mykey1) # A = [(1,8), (4,3), (5,9), (7,2)]
B = sorted(L, key=mykey2) # B = [(7,2), (4,3), (1,8), (5,9)]
```

when working on the sublist made of `A[0:2]` which is `[(1,8), (4,3)]`, is there some tricky way to iterate over `[(4,3), (1,8)]` (since the object `(4,3)` comes before object `(1,8)` according to the key `mykey2`. I would like to avoid iterating over any other object than those actually belonging to `A[0:2]` for that purpose?

I can do it with complexity O(*n*) by iterating over the whole `B` and checking if the object is in the sublist (which is not difficult to achieve by adding some field to the object giving its position in `A`); can I do better?

Answer (score 0):

It has been a very long time since i used Python, but wouldn't something like this work?

```
C = sorted(A[0:2], key=mykey2)
```

then iterate over C after applying this "B" sort/key to the A sublist to generate it, or you could instead subtract the lists

```
C = B - A[2:2]
```

If your sublists can be generated incrementally, this could be a simple way to generate them, already in B sorted order.  Rather than start from A sublists and try to iterate through them in B order, turn it around and start from B and generate the sublists by taking away items in A order.

Or am I missing something here.  This seems too simple an answer.

Comment: Hummm, I think you will introduce O(_n log n_) complexity (though I have to check it since you sort a smaller list); I think the O(_n_) solution (iterating over `B` and checking if it belongs to the sublist) would be still better. I would like rather to pre-compute as many things as possible before entering the algorithm.

Comment: How are you selecting out sublists?  The trick might be in that operation.  If you can start from B and extract A[4], you would have A[0:3] ordered in B order.  If you take this further, you could incrementally generate your sublists by taking out the pieces that you don't want.  just another idea.

Comment: I have to think about that; it may indeed help. I need a little time to figure it out.

Comment: It is the only thing I can think of to take advantage of the fact that you already have B in the order you want the A sublists.  Turn the problem around so that you are generating the sublists starting with B and taking out items in A order, rather than starting with A, generating the sublist and then trying to iterate/sort them in B order.

Answer (score 0):

```
I would suggest the next code snippet:

    L = [(7,2), (4,3), (5,9), (1,8)]
    mykey1 = lambda e: e[0]
    mykey2 = lambda e: e[1]
    A = sorted(L, key=mykey1)
    C = [sorted(_, key=mykey2) for _ in (A[0:_] for _ in (_ for _ in range(1, len(A) + 1)))]

C will be a list containing the sub-lists:
[[(1, 8)],
 [(4, 3), (1, 8)],
 [(4, 3), (1, 8), (5, 9)],
 [(7, 2), (4, 3), (1, 8), (5, 9)]]

Or, if we want to make C a [generator][1] (instead of a list); for lists we are keeping all elements in memory (performance issue) :

    C = (sorted(_, key=mykey2) for _ in (A[0:_] for _ in (_ for _ in range(1, len(A) + 1))))

Hope it helps.
```

Comment: This assumes he is only interested in sublists of A starting at the first item in A.